# What is the difference between deploying an artifact into Artifactory with 'mvn deploy' command and with Artifactory UI?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I usually use `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` command to update my dependencies to the latest ones which other teams have been deployed to our free Jfrog's Artifactory server on our local address : `http://192.168.100.243:8082/artifactory/X_Douran/`.
My problem is when I deploy an artifact (a jar file) with Artifactory UI or with curl (using Jfrog's Rest Api), the command `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` doesn't work correctly and do not update my pom but when I run `mvn clean deploy` on my source code of my dependent project then running `mvn versions:use-latest-versions` on my final project it works correctly and do update my dependency in my pom.
So I want to know what is the different between deploying via Artifactory UI and deploying via `mvn clean deploy` ?

Comment: I need to be able to deploy via artifactory UI, because we have an employee responsible for uploading jar artifacts and she doesn't know how to code she is only able to do it via web UI and  with this problem we cant use `mvn versions:use-latest-versions`. Other teams send their jar files to her. sometimes jars doesn't even has a code and teams change them by hand, putting .class files in jars.

Comment: If your teams don't have build systems, you should strongly consider it.  Manual steps can be forgotten...

Answer (score 1):

1. You always need to deploy the POM along the JAR, otherwise Maven will not work correctly with these dependencies. Furthermore, you need to make sure that the metadata files are updated. I am not sure that Artifactory does this if you deploy using curl or the UI.
2. Deploying your own JARs regularly through the UI is not recommended. You should build them on a build server (like Jenkins) and then automatically deploy them to Artifactory.
3. Changing JAR files "by hand" should be forbidden.